# Are the bad effects of fatigue stronger for highly neurotic people?

Tags: conflict, neuroticism, fatigue, irritability

Fatigue causes many [bad effects](https://www.betterhealth.vic.gov.au/health/conditionsandtreatments/fatigue#symptoms-of-fatigue) like *irritability*, *poor concentration*, *reduced ability to pay attention to the situation at hand*, *low motivation*.

**Question:** Are the interpersonal bad effects of fatigue (*irritability*, and *reduced ability to pay attention to the situation at hand*) stronger for highly neurotic people, given that one of the two components of neuroticism is volatility (which encompasses emotional lability, irritability or anger, and difficulty controlling emotional impulses, [De Young et al. 2007](https://doi.org/10.1037/0022-3514.93.5.880))?

**Nb:** As a sidenote (given that one question must be asked at a time) I suppose that, similarly, the detrimental effects that a bad alimentation has on mood might be stronger in highly neurotic people compared to in more emotionally stable people.

**References:**

DeYoung, C. G., Quilty, L. C., & Peterson, J. B. (2007). Between facets and domains: 10 aspects of the Big Five. Journal of personality and social psychology, 93(5), 880. https://doi.org/10.1037/0022-3514.93.5.880 [[PDF](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Lena-Quilty/publication/5863998_Between_Facets_and_Domains_10_Aspects_of_the_Big_Five/links/09e41509d11bf03849000000/Between-Facets-and-Domains-10-Aspects-of-the-Big-Five.pdf)]